# Remove query string from inline css

Tags: django, query-string, django-compressor

I'm using the django compressor for my small site and I don't want the query strings on images. e.g. images/header.png?9e1ed2cd7d15

Is there someway to disable it?

Comment: I'm interested in this too -- I'm concerned that the query strings will cause many proxies (esp. squid with default configuration) not to cache resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django Compressor lets you control how your CSS is compressed by choosing from a set of filters that will be applied via the [`django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS`](https://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS) setting.

Note that the default filter, *CssAbsoluteFilter*, normalizes the URLs used in url() CSS statements, and appends a hash to the processed URLs. You can control the type of hash that is generated with the `django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD` setting.

According to the documentation your only choices for the hashing method are 'mtime' or 'content', but it seems there was [a commit made two weeks ago](https://github.com/thenewguy/django_compressor/commit/14f6bd506d3bdf0a7a63ddf7a8a98d4d777b7756) that added support for None as an option too. In theory if you install the latest version from GitHub, and set that option to None, that should get rid of those query strings.

Failing that, you could always try removing the *CssAbsoluteFilter* altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Clean installation via `pip install django_compressor` ([detailed here](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#installation)) should work just fine, as it did for me. It only hashes css file, use this code to compress:

```
{% compress css %}
  <link href="yourstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endcompress %}
```